White Box Rendering in Header in Older Outlook Windows 10?
enter White Box Rendering
I'm having this issue in the Windows Outlook 10 that is rendering this huge white box above my logo and I don't know where it's coming from or what it's trying to read. It renders fine in the web version of outlook and the new one but it'd be nice to fix that in case there are people using the older version still. Anyone ever have this issue or see a fix?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no, email=no, url=no">
   <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
   <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
   <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
    <title>MedMutual Master Template</title>
   <!--[if mso]>
      <noscript>
         <xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
         </xml>
      </noscript>
   <![endif]-->
    
   <style type="text/css">
      table {
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td {
            padding: 0;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 30px;
        }
        h3 {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        h4 {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        h5 {
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 15px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        p {
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height:17px;
        }
        img {
            border: 0;
            height:auto;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #00968F;
        }
       a.visited {
           color: #6D2077;
       }
      .content {
         line-height: 20px;
         font-size: 16px;
      }
       
      .btn {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #FFF;
         background-color: #6D2077;
         border-radius: 3px;
      }
       .footer {
           padding: 15px 20px 0 20px;
           color: #ffffff;
           text-align: left;
           font-size: 12px;
       }
        .column .column-one-half .nav {
           width: 50%;
       }
       .socials td {
           vertical-align: bottom;
       }

      span.Object {
         color: inherit !important;
      }
      span.Object-hover {
         color: inherit !important;
         text-decoration:none !important;
      }

      u + .body .gmail-blend-screen { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:screen; }
        u + .body .gmail-blend-difference { background:#000; mix-blend-mode:difference; }

      .ExternalClass {
         width: 100%;
      }
        .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {
         line-height: 100%;
      }

      a[x-apple-data-detectors=true]{
         color: inherit !important;
         text-decoration: inherit !important;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 599.98px) {

         .padding{
              padding: 10px 0 10px !important;
          }
         .banner {
            height: auto !important;
            padding: 0 0 60px !important;
         }
         .column-wrapper .padding {
            padding-right: 0 !important;
            padding-left: 0 !important;
         }
          
         .column-wrapper .column,
         .column-wrapper .column img {
            width: 100% !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
         }
         .column-wrapper {
            padding: 0 75px !important;
         }
         table.mobile-hide {
             display: none !important;
             width: 0 !important;
             height: 0 !important;
             opacity: 0 !important;
             visibility: collapse !important;
          }
        .column .column-one-half .nav {
           width: 100% !important;
            text-align: center !important;}
         
          .column-one-half {
              width: 100% !important;
          }

         .column-one-third img.one-third-col-img {
            max-width: 60% !important;
            height: auto !important;
            padding-top: 15px !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
         }
         .column-two-third .content {
            text-align: center !important;
         }
         .column-two-third {
            padding-bottom: 30px !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;

         }
         .column-wrapper .column-one-fourth {
            width: 150px !important;
            max-width: 150px !important;
            align-content: center !important;
         }
         .column-one-fourth .content img {
            max-width: 120px !important;
             align-content: center !important;
         }
         .footer {
           padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
           color: #ffffff;
           text-align: center;
           font-size: 12px;
       }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 499.98px) {
         .banner {
            padding: 0 0 50px !important;
         }
         .column-wrapper {
            padding: 0 45px !important;
         }
         table.mobile-hide {
             display: none !important;
             width: 0 !important;
             height: 0 !important;
             opacity: 0 !important;
             visibility: collapse !important;
          }
          .column .column-one-half .nav img {
              max-width:100px !important;
          }
          .footer {
           padding: 10px 15px 0 15px;
           color: #ffffff;
           text-align: center;
           font-size: 12px;
       }
          .socials {
              text-align: center !important;
          }
          
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 399.98px) {
         .banner {
            padding: 0 0 40px !important;
         }
         .column-wrapper {
            padding: 0 20px !important;
         }
         table.mobile-hide {
             display: none !important;
             width: 0 !important;
             height: 0 !important;
             opacity: 0 !important;
             visibility: collapse !important;
          }
          .footer {
           padding: 5px 10px 0 10px;
           color: #ffffff;
           text-align: center;
           font-size: 12px;
       }
          .socials {
              text-align: center !important;
          }
      }

      :root {
         color-scheme: light dark;
         supported-color-schemes: light dark;
      }
      @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
         body, table, .darkmode-bg {
            background: #2d2d2d !important;
            color: #ffffff !important;
         }
         [data-ogsc] body, table, .darkmode-bg {
            background: #2d2d2d !important;
            color: #ffffff !important;
         }
         .darkmode-transparent {
            background-color: transparent !important;
         }
         [data-ogsc] .darkmode-transparent {
            background-color: transparent !important;
         }
      }

   </style>

    <!--[if mso]>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {background-color: #dde0e1 !important;}
         body, table, td, p, a {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;}
         table {border-spacing: 0 !important;border-collapse: collapse !important;}
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
    
</head>
<body class="body" xml:lang="en" style="margin:0;padding:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#dde0e1;">

   <div style="width: 100%; table-layout:fixed; background-color: #dde0e1; color:#3d3d3d; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 auto 40px;">
      <div style="max-width: 600px; background-color: #fafdfe; color:#3d3d3d; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);margin: 0 auto;">

         <!-- Preheader (remove comment) -->
         <div style="font-size: 0px; color: #fafdfe; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 0px; display: none; max-width: 0px; max-height: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide:all;">
            <!-- Add Preheader Text Here (85-100 characters in length) -->
             &zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;
         </div>
         <!-- End Preheader (remove comment) -->
      
         <!--[if mso]>
            <table width="600" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse:collapse; color: #3d3d3d;" role="presentation">
            <tr>
            <td style="padding:0;">
         <![endif]-->

         <table align="center" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse: collapse; color:#3d3d3d; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; background-color: #fafdfe; margin: 0 auto; padding:0; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;" role="presentation">
     
<!-- START TWO COLUMNS -->
            <tr>
               <td style="padding: 0;">
                  <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" cellspacing="0" borderspacing="0" role="presentation">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="column-wrapper nav" style="padding: 0; font-size: 0; text-align: left; background-color:#00968F;">

                           <!--[if mso]>
                              <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                              <tr>
                              <td width="300" valign="top" style="padding: 0;">
                           <![endif]-->

                           <table class="column column-one-half nav" style="border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: middle; width: 50%; max-width: 300px; display: inline-block;" role="presentation">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="padding" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;">

                                    <table class="content" style="border-spacing: 0; text-align: left;" role="presentation">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>

                                             <!--[if mso]>
                                                <v:roundrect stroke="false" style="width:195pt; height:147pt;" arcsize="4%">
                                                   <v:fill sizes="195pt,147pt" type="frame" src="https://info.medmutual.com/assets/responsysimages/content/medmutualoh/MM_Logo_H(WHITE).png" href="https://www.medmutual.com">
                                                   <w:anchorlock/>
                                                </v:roundrect>
                                             <![endif]-->

                                             <a href="https://www.medmutual.com" target="_blank"><img src="https://info.medmutual.com/assets/responsysimages/content/medmutualoh/MM_Logo_H(WHITE).png" alt="Medical Mutual Logo" title="Logo" width="200" style="border: 0;max-width: 200px;"></a>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>

                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>

                           <!--[if mso]>
                           </td><td width="300" valign="middle" style="padding: 0;">
                           <![endif]-->

                           <table class="column column-one-half nav mobile-hide" style="border-spacing: 0; vertical-align: middle; width: 50%; max-width: 300px; display: inline-block;" role="presentation">
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="padding" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 80px;">
                                    <table class="content" style="border-spacing: 0; text-align: right;" role="presentation">
                                       <tr>
                                          <td>
                                             <a href="https://www.medmutual.com" target="_blank" style="color:#FFF;">
                                                <h4>Click to Visit MedMutual.com</h4>
                                             </a>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </table>

                           <!--[if mso]>
                              </td>
                              </tr>
                              </table>
                           <![endif]-->

                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </td>
            </tr>
<!-- END TWO COLUMNS -->


This white box in particular comes from the following section in your code:
<!--[if mso]>
   <v:roundrect stroke="false" style="width:195pt; height:147pt;" arcsize="4%">
      <v:fill sizes="195pt,147pt" type="frame" src="https://info.medmutual.com/assets/responsysimages/content/medmutualoh/MM_Logo_H(WHITE).png" href="https://www.medmutual.com">
      <w:anchorlock/>
   </v:roundrect>
<![endif]-->

This code is VML (a vector image language, akin to SVG). This is usually used to trick Outlook to display background images or make rounded corners. A lot of email developers use only tools like Buttons.cm and Backgrounds.cm to generate these code.
Since it looks like you're not needing it there, I suggest you remove this code completely.
